# "string indices must be integers" error when parsing JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have the following JSON and I would like to extract all the email's within it. The json is exported from AWS cognito and I have no control over how it is structured.

```json
expected_value = """{
  "Users": [
    {
      "Username": "testUserName1",
      "Attributes": [
        {
          "Name": "testName1",
          "Value": "TestValue1@email.com"
        }
      ],
      "UserCreateDate": "2021-09-13T11:16:02.627000+01:00",
      "UserLastModifiedDate": "2021-09-13T11:16:02.627000+01:00",
      "Enabled": true,
      "UserStatus": "UNCONFIRMED"
    },
    {
      "Username": "testUsername2",
      "Attributes": [
        {
          "Name": "testEmail2",
          "Value": "testValue2@email.com"
        }
      ],
      "UserCreateDate": "2021-02-19T11:52:52.465000+00:00",
      "UserLastModifiedDate": "2021-02-19T11:52:52.465000+00:00",
      "Enabled": true,
      "UserStatus": "UNCONFIRMED"
    }
  ]
}"""
```

I have the following code where I am feeding in the json for now as expected value:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    data = json.dumps(expected_value)
    y = json.loads(data)
    email = y['Users'][0]['Attributes'][0]['Value']
```

But I get the following error:

```json
{
  "errorMessage": "string indices must be integers",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "requestId": "622258cc-8248-4901-8a39-fc6e0a24229c",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 145, in lambda_handler\n    email = y['Users'][0]['Attributes'][0]['Value']\n"
  ]
}
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

As requested, a REPREX which still throws the error:

Comment: `item['Users']['Attributes']` needs `item['Users']['Attributes'][0]` or some other index before `['Value']` as Attributes is a list of objects

Comment: @depperm You'd also need `[0]` after `["Users"]` as well.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @depperm @jjramsey I have tried the following but it returns the same error:
```store_details['Value'] = item['Users'][0]['Attributes'][0]['Value']```

Comment: @martineau Cannot get reprex to format properly, will add to main question

Comment: you get the exact same error? is this all the code? are you sure you've posted `store_details` fully/completely?

Comment: Everything should be in your question itself. The code in your question makes no sense. It references undefined variables like `expected_value` and the `process_event()` function returns no value, among other things.

Comment: Also, don't dump a string just to load it again

Comment: here is a [replit](https://replit.com/@depperm/ReadJSON#main.py) that works, reading json from string and reading email works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lookking at the code that has been shown, the value of the `expected_value` variable is already a JSON-formatted string. When `json.dumps()` is applied to it, the value is "embedded" in another (redundant) JSON "layer".

So either remove the `"""` triple quotation marks from you `expected_value` or remove `json.dumps()` from you function; in the latter case the `expected_value` should be passed directly to `json.loads()`:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    y = json.loads(expected_value)
    email = y['Users'][0]['Attributes'][0]['Value']
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me. Note I removed the dumping and reloading of the data you currently have in your question.

```
import json


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    data = json.loads(event)
    email = data['Users'][0]['Attributes'][0]['Value']
    print(f'{email=}')  # -> email='TestValue1@email.com'


event = '''
{
  "Users": [
    {
      "Username": "testUserName1",
      "Attributes": [
        {
          "Name": "testName1",
          "Value": "TestValue1@email.com"
        }
      ],
      "UserCreateDate": "2021-09-13T11:16:02.627000+01:00",
      "UserLastModifiedDate": "2021-09-13T11:16:02.627000+01:00",
      "Enabled": true,
      "UserStatus": "UNCONFIRMED"
    },
    {
      "Username": "testUsername2",
      "Attributes": [
        {
          "Name": "testEmail2",
          "Value": "testValue2@email.com"
        }
      ],
      "UserCreateDate": "2021-02-19T11:52:52.465000+00:00",
      "UserLastModifiedDate": "2021-02-19T11:52:52.465000+00:00",
      "Enabled": true,
      "UserStatus": "UNCONFIRMED"
    }
  ]
}
'''

lambda_handler(event, None)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user_list = []
for item in json:
    users_list.append(item['Users'][0]['Attributes'][0]['Value'])
```

because 'Attributes' here is a list of dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

> would like to extract all the email's within it

The lambda event should already be JSON, IIRC

As the error says, you'll need to index the lists using numbers, or use a for-each loop over the whole list

```
emails = []
for user in event.get('Users', []):  # assuming event is already a dict
    for a in user.get('Attributes', []):
        # probably also want to get the Name field and check the property is actually an email 
        v = a.get('Value')
        if v:
            emails.append(v)
print(emails)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. My goal is to trigger this lambda through a cloud watch event. Essentially what I am trying to do is get a json from AWS cognito which contains all the unconfirmed users. I am currently expecting this to be a function in the lambda and store it as "expected_value" for now.

Comment: This code can be placed anywhere that some `event` variable is defined.